# Is it necessary to do train-test split when we are interested in understanding the model rather than predicting?

Tags: regression, inference, random-forest, causality, train-test-split

In machine learning we are taught to always do validation of some sort, for instance by creating a hold out validation set that is used to test the performance of the model.

However, in some use cases we are interested in understanding the underlying relationship between variables.

If we take a linear regression for instance, we could use the coefficient to interpret the effect of each metric.

In this paradigm, should we also do train/test split? if I use a random forest for instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This question gets to the core of the complex relationship between Machine Learning, Statistical Inference, and Causal Inference

#### 1. Machine Learning

In conventional supervised machine learning, a *model* is simply a flexible curve-fitting device. There is typically no intention to make statistical or causal assumptions about the underlying real-world process which is reflected in the flexibility of the *models* used (e.g. random forests, neural networks, etc.). Due to their flexibility, such *models* may overfit the training data, which is why it's important to split data into train/test.

#### 2. Statistical Inference

Statistical inference tries to make statements about properties of the distribution of an entire population given finite samples. The uncertainty arises from the fact that relationships in small sample may arise by chance and may not hold true on the population level (that is, asymptotically for infinite samples).
Statistical inference typically specifies target parameters ("estimands") by proposing a parametric *model* of the population probability distribution. One can then estimate the parameters on finite samples and quantify the uncertainty of the estimates. In this procedure, any data not used to estimate the target parameter would be a waste - it could only increase the uncertainty of the estimate.

However, there is still an analogous practice to train/test splits. As some statisticians (famously John Tukey) have noticed, the decision about what *models* may plausibly describe the data also tend to be made on the basis of inspecting the very same data in a process Tukey named "Exploratory Data Analysis". If one comes up with a hypothesis about the data by inspecting it, only to confirm it on that same data, of course the parameter estimates it would most likely be significant. It may therefore be useful to split data into two parts, on for "exploration" (the training set), and one for "confirmation" (the test set), to avoid confirmation bias (akin to data leakage in ML).

#### 3. Causal Inference

Causal inference is much more ambitious than purely statistical inference. The goal is not only to find population-level parameters, but these parameters should correspond to stable relationships that can predict what would happen when one intervenes on variables. In this context, a *model* is not merely a model of the distribution of the variables (is in statistical inference), but a *model* of the data-generating process itself. In real-world applications the *model* is often based on domain knowledge, although there are many attempts to discover causal structure from data. As with statistical inference, there is a danger of confirmation bias or data leakage (on the side of the domain expert or the causal discovery algorithm). However, causal inference typically relies on other, arguably much stronger, assumptions such as "no unobserved confounders". This is probably why considerations about train/test splits take a back seat compared to other considerations.

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful. 
Do you have some resources to understand better?
What you said made a lot of sense, but I have many more questions

Comment: On a very superficial level one could observe that there is a train/test split in ML, sometimes an exploration/confirmation split in statistical inference, and causality is busy fighting with other problems. For a more in-depth understanding I don't know a single source, unfortunately. As for some more general works, I can recommend the preface and first chapter of "Statistical Learning Theory" by Vapnik and the [Book of Why](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/WHY/) on causal inference. But perhaps someone else might know of a more concise work that compares the different perspectives.

Answer (score 0):

Even when using "machine learning methods" for causal inference, which usually implies semiparametric estimation of causal effects, cross-fitting is commonly used to reduce bias from regularization/overfitting and produce desirable statistical properties of the estimator such as valid confidence intervals. For cross-fitting, you split your data into two, use one subset to pick you model (e.g., select controlling variables) and use the other to estimate the parameters of your model. You then repeat this for all subsets and average your results from different splits to recover the loss of statistical efficiency from splitting your dataset. So it's the same idea as "train-test split". You can read more here for example: Ratkovic, Marc. "Rehabilitating the Regression: Honest and Valid Causal Inference through Machine Learning." (2019). Random forests are very commonly used in modern causal inference techniques using machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for random forest, if we grow enough trees, the out-of-bag predictions approximate the average prediction error (the error estimated using a test dataset) of a random forest. So, we don't really need a test dataset in that case. This result is shown in Tomoshige Nakamura's (2023) presentation: https://math.bu.edu/BKT2023/slides/Nakamura-variable_importance_for_causal_forest.pdf